# A click on module header in my joomla website to lead to an article

Tags: php, javascript, html, joomla2.5

I m using this pause scrolling news module, which i got from the joomla extensions.

> http://kksou.com/php-gtk2/Joomla/Pausing-up-down-Scroller-module.php

It also has a relevant plugin to be installed, When the both module and plugin are installed & enabled this works. Yes this works in my site !!

But my requirement is when i click the module heading it must lead to another article, unfortunately this module does not have this option. I need to play with the code. Please instruct me the steps to code in this module. Would be wonderful if you help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a content plugin.

You can edit the code in the folder : your_joomla_site\plugins\content\pausing_up_down_scroller

Comment: Yeah, i have these files with me inside the plugin as one css file, two php files where one is a lib file and a xml file, But since i m new to joomla and php i m not sure as how to write the code in this. Can u instruct me the steps to code here ?